# Using graphs to quantify the structure/pattern or correlation among the elements of supposedly random matrix

Tags: correlation, random-graphs, random-matrices, pattern-recognition

Let's say I have a supposedly random real symmetric matrix. How to use graphs to quantitatively (with a numerical focus) examine any structure/pattern or correlation among its elements ?